# Support for non-sticky sessions in spring-security-saml2-core?

Tags: spring-saml

I see from http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html#configuration-load-balancing that stickysessions are required when using a loadbalancer.

Is there any hope for support for non-sticky sessions in a future release?

-Kaj :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be need for sticky sessions in case you replicate your HTTP sessions to all nodes in the cluster. It's also not needed in case you use IDP-initialized SSO without Single Logout. One more option is to add bean `EmptyStorageFactory` which removes certain validations based on sent `AuthnRequest` (like checking of InResponseTo field).

There's always hope, but I don't think I'll be writing this anytime soon. Contributions welcome.